# StatusBar - Dynamic items and static items

Tags: wpf, statusbar, itemsource

I have a statusbar, which will contain some dynamic statusbaritems and some "hard-coded" statusbaritems. For some reason the dynamic status bar items are not displayed, even thought the binding with the ViewModel property is done and I can see the items using Live Visual Tree

This is the statusbar

```
<StatusBar x:Name="StatusBar" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <StatusBar.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.5"/>
            </StatusBar.Background>
            <StatusBarItem Height="60" Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Image Source="Logo.png" ></Image>
            </StatusBarItem>           
            <Separator></Separator>        
            <StatusBar.ItemTemplate>                
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="ASDF"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </StatusBar.ItemTemplate>
        </StatusBar>
```

[image]

This is the statusbar at runtime.

As you can see there are 5 items that are visible and 2 items from the observable collection that do not render on the UI.

This is how the UI looks 
[image]

The green/blue part is visible, the rest of the StatusBar space is taken by the last separator. My dynamic items are no where to be found.

Any ideas? Can I make both dynamic/static items work in the same StatusBar? Or do I need to add 2 statusbar one for dynamic and the other one for static content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I make both dynamic/static items work in the same StatusBar?

No. You cannot both bind to an `ItemsSource` and add static objects to the `Items` collection.

If your binding would work, you would get an `InvalidOperationException` saying that '`Items` collection must be empty before using `ItemsSource`.'

What you should do is to add your static items to the source collection in your view model.

Comment: Yeah, just added 2 statusbar's and it works. Well the question is kind of answered. I can't add the static items to the collection as they have totally different design. I will have to stick with 2 statusbars. Thank you.